# Time Machine keeps quitting

Tags: backup, time-machine, high-sierra

I upgraded a early 2013 MBP Retina to 10.13.2, and obtained a new external 4TB drive to do TM backups to.

Time Machine now pukes after a semi-random period of time -- 20 to 60 minutes.  Here's what the console says

```
default 17:52:06.139471 -0600   powerd  Process backupd.8811 ClientDied PreventUserIdleSystemSleep "Time Machine backup" age:00:18:24  id:4295008645 [System: PrevIdle DeclUser IntPrevDisp kDisp]


default 17:52:06.140737 -0600   powerd  Process backupd.8811 ClientDied BackgroundTask "Time Machine backup" age:00:18:24  id:47244681604 [System: PrevIdle DeclUser IntPrevDisp kDisp]
```

What's more, the icon in the menu bar no longer spins.

What in the world is going on?

Comment: For whatever it's worth, I simply got around this moronic problem by taking it out of Apple's hands and installing Carbon Copy Cloner.

Apple has badly dropped the ball by breaking one of MacOS's most simple, intuitive and reliable features. I've been reading for years in the post-iOS world about how they'd like to get out of the computer business; I think things like this show how they are doing it. Death by a thousand cuts for a platform that once ruled personal computing. What a bummer.